# Error creating HttpTrigger Azure Function with CosmosDB document output

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I want to make an Azure Function that takes a JSON body passed to it and inserts this document in to an Azure COSMOSDB instance.

To do so, I created this function in the Azure Functions Portal:
[image: Azure Function configuration]

And implement the function like so:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

using System.Net;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log, object outputDocument)
{
    var requestContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    log.Verbose($@"Received request:\n{requestContent}");

    var newDoc = JObject.Parse(requestContent);
    newDoc["Id"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    newDoc["shardKey"] = newDoc.Value<string>(@"Id").Substring(8);

    outputDocument = newDoc;

    return req.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

In the portal, I put in an easy sample doc:

```
{
  "prop1": 2,
  "prop2": "2017-02-20",
}
```

and click 'Run'

I'm immediately met with
[image: portal IDE error]

as an overlay in the portal IDE along with

```
{
  "id": "145ee924-f824-4064-8364-f96dc12ab138",
  "requestId": "5a27c287-2c91-40f5-be52-6a79c7c86bc2",
  "statusCode": 500,
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "'UploadDocumentToCosmos' can't be invoked from Azure WebJobs SDK. Is it missing Azure WebJobs SDK attributes?"
}
```

in the log area.

There seems to be nothing I can do to fix the issue, yet I sure feel like I'm doing everything right.

What do I need to do to simply take a JSON object as an HTTP Request to an Azure Function, and insert/upsert said object in to an Azure Cosmos DB instance??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For async functions you should use `IAsyncCollector`:

```cs
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log, 
    IAsyncCollector<object> outputDocuments)
{
    ...
    await outputDocuments.AddAsync(newDoc);
}
```

Comment: This compiles but is worth noting [isn't in the documentation at all](https://www.screencast.com/t/ea0M4zMcyIcB).

Haven't yet ran it.

Comment: You can read more about Azure Functions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp . This document talks about IAsyncCollector

Comment: Thanks @RafatSarosh. While the documentation mentions that type as something you *can* put stuff in to, it would be much more affordable to have that type spelled out next to each binding to which it applies (cosmosdb, etc). Because I also can use "DocumentDB" as a binding type.
In addition, surrounding it by all the CSX stuff made me ignore it completely; I was developing in Visual Studio.

Answer (score -2):

Can you try adding `out` to `dynamic outputDocument`?

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log, out dynamic outputDocument)
```

Comment: will give it a shot. however, developing in the portal means this shouldn't be needed; output params & their names are defined in the bindings.

I also updated my code; i was *trying* `dynamic` but originally had `object` (per the documentation)

Comment: no can do:

`2017-10-04T17:34:27.844 Script for function 'UploadDocumentToCosmos' changed. Reloading.`
`2017-10-04T17:34:27.985 run.csx(6,103): error CS1988: Async methods cannot have ref or out parameters`
`2017-10-04T17:34:27.985 Compilation failed.`